# What is the difference between `on_validation_epoch_end` and `validation_epoch_end` in Pytorch-lightning?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Inside a `LightningModule`,Pycharm allows 2 auto complete methods:

```
class MyModel(LightningModule):

    def on_validation_epoch_end(self):

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outs):
```

with `on_validation_epoch_end` referenced in `hooks.py`

```
def on_validation_epoch_end(self) -> None:
    """
    Called in the validation loop at the very end of the epoch.
    """
    # do something when the epoch ends
```

and

`validation_epoch_end` called in `evaluation_loop.py` as `eval_results = model.validation_epoch_end(eval_results)` leading to `__run_eval_epoch_end`.

---

What is the purpose of each of those?

I can only assume one is deprecated. Could not find any relevant docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#hooks) is a pseudocode that shows when the hooks are called, and I think it makes it quite explicit that you are right : these two functions are redundant (literally called at the same place with the same arguments) and I would say that `validation_epoch_end` is the one to be considered deprecated here, since it's not mentioned in the doc whereas the hooks (of the form `on_event_start/end`) are extensively explained